# Using SET !VAR1 EVAL in javascript iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros, data-extraction

I have a .iim iMacros file for extracting text from a website, it looks like this:

```
SET !DATASOURCE listofurls.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{CSV}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var a=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var b=a.indexOf(\"total\"); var c=parseFloat(a.substring((b+9),(b+9+3))); c")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=result.csv
```

It runs good in Play (Loop) mode, but need to automatically run as a loop automatically launching it from a shell script. As a normal .iim file can't be automated as a loop I tried to convert it to iMacros javascript:

```
var accounts = 10;
for(i = 1; i <= accounts; i++){

iimDisplay("Current loop: "+ i);

var extract;
extract =  "CODE:";
extract +=  "SET !DATASOURCE followersapi.csv" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{CSV}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !VAR1 EVAL("var a=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var b=a.indexOf(\"total\"); var c=parseFloat(a.substring((b+9),(b+9+3))); c")" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=result.csv" + "\n"; 

iimSet("CSV", i);
iimPlay(extract);

}
```

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line 23 (Error code: -991)

And after some research modified this line it from this:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var a=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var b=a.indexOf(\"total\"); var c=parseFloat(a.substring((b+9),(b+9+3))); c")
```

to this:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var a=\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'; var b=a.indexOf(\"total\"); var c=parseFloat(a.substring((b+9),(b+9+3))); c\)
```

And then I get this error:

> wrong format of SET command, line 9 (Error code: 910)

Any ideas on how I could get this working? I also tried to launch the .iim file from a .js file and loop it from there, but then the !LOOP is always 1 and it always reads the first line of the csv.. so it's pretty useless.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
extract +=  'SET !VAR1 EVAL("var a=\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'; var b=a.indexOf(\'total\'); var c=parseFloat(a.substring((b+9),(b+9+3))); c")' + "\n";
```

Comment: Woho! Incredible! You just changed all the " to '.. why so? Is it a bug on iMacros or it should be written this way?

Comment: That’s the rule of using ‘iMacros’ + JavaScript as to string notation. You also may write like so: `extract +=  "SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var a='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var b=a.indexOf('total'); var c=parseFloat(a.substring((b+9),(b+9+3))); c\")" + "\n";` .